# Wired to wifi works. Wifi to wired won't work

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have all my devices on WLAN except my desktop which is on LAN. I cannot SSH or FTP into my desktop from any WLAN device.  I can however, SSH/FTP from LAN to WLAN.

Oddly, ping works on everything.

**Works:**
WLAN to WLAN, LAN to WLAN

**Does not work:**
WLAN to LAN

My router is a TP-LINK WR1043ND v1 with the latest firmware (3.13.13 Build 130428 Rel.58290n)

AP isolation is disabled.

My desktop is running Linux Mint 14 MATE 64

Any suggestions?

Another way to state the problem for Google searches:  Wifi computers won't talk to wired computers.

Comment: Are both LAN and WLAN the same IP subnet? After you ping from WLAN to LAN, does your WLAN client have the LAN desktop's MAC address in its ARP table? Does the LAN desktop have the WLAN client's MAC address in its ARP table? Is the WLAN client associated to the main/primary SSID of the AP, or to a secondary or guest SSID? Does `ping -s 1472 <IPAddrOfTarget>` work?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  `ping -s 1472 <IPAddrOfTarget>` works great.  In my router's settings  my machines appear in the ARP table and I have them binded on MAC address.  There does not appear to be a guest account on this router.  They are connected to the primary SSID.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I didn't ask about your router's ARP table, I asked about the LAN desktop and the WLAN client. For those two devices to talk to each other, they need each others' entry in their own ARP tables. Is that happening?

Comment: *"Wifi to wired won't work"* is not a valid assessment or conclusion.  You only report that you cannot connect to one specific host on the LAN.  Have you proven that the desktop can be connected by SSH or FTP using a wired connection?  You could have a permissions or configuration issue on that desktop that prevents any and all SSH or FTP connections.

Comment: Thanks for the help Spiff and sawdust.  This issue was related to a MAC clone setting in my router.  I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I had the "MAC Clone" setting turned on in my router.  The "WAN MAC Address" had my desktop's MAC address.  I changed it back to the router's default MAC address and restarted my router and all machines on my network.

The first ssh attempted failed as normal.  The second succeeded.  Since then I have restarted everything on my LAN and the router as well and everything now works as expected.

Since the WIFI card had a different MAC address than the LAN card, WIFI connections were permitted, but LAN connections were never routed to my desktop.

Thanks everyone for the help.